# Does it help to run stuff in virtual machine for privacy purpose?

Tags: virtual-machine, virus

Let's say I have windows but I read my e-mails inside a linux virtual machine. Are my e-mails a little more protected from a backdoor affecting windows or is it trivial for the backdoor to access what happens in the virtual box and it make no difference with me reading my e-mail directly inside windows ?

Thanks

Comment: Switch to Linux on your host then you won't need VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a virtual box is a emulated (computer inside computer) program.  It may know about the PC's hardware, but does not know about the PC's files.  However, the virus may still be able to access the **machine files** and access your virtual machine from there and read emails.  It will be a **great** idea to install an antivirus, as it can still escape through emulated ports, networking, transferred files, and/or through x86 virtualization.